# playframework get the index using @repeat?

Tags: playframework

How do I get the index where I am using Play Framework twirl template stuff?

I want to have:

```
@repeat(questionForm("correct"), min = 0) { correct =>
    @b3.hidden( "correct[INDEX_HERE].id", correct("id").value, 'attr -> false )           
}
```

But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about making a little helper called `repeatWithIndex`

```
@(field:Field, min: Int = 1)(implicit f: (Field, Int) => Html)
@{
  (0 until math.max(if(field.indexes.isEmpty) 0 else field.indexes.max + 1, min)).map(i => f(field("[" + i + "]"), i))
}
```

then you could reference the index like so?

```
@repeatWithIndex(questionForm("correct"), min = 0) { (correct, index) =>
    @b3.hidden(s"correct[$index].id", correct("id").value, 'attr -> false )           
}
```

Comment: just riffing off source: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/Helpers.scala#L103

Answer (score 0):

`repeatWithIndex` helper is now part of the framework.
 According to [official docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaForms#Repeated-values) you can get the index similarly to solution provided by @tgk:

```
@helper.repeatWithIndex(myForm("emails"), min = 1) { (emailField, index) =>
    @helper.inputText(emailField, '_label -> ("email #" + index))
}
```

Here is the pull request that added `repeatWithIndex` helper:
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/7025